# How do i get rid of: HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL?

Tags: java, web-services, http, web-applications, servlets

I have been breaking my head over this issue over the past few hours. This is my first attempt at writing a web app and deploying it to the apache tomcat web container. I follow a simple tutorial from [here](http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/java_web_programming/servlets/) and then end up getting this error. Tried a few solutions as appear in other posts about the same issue but none seemed to have worked so far. I am pasting snippets of and web.xml, website.xml and my code files respectively. Kindly see if i am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>website.web.TestServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**website.xml:**

```
<Context path="/website" docBase="C:\Users\Priyankar\workspace\website\web" />
```

**HomeServlet.java**

```
package website.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
               throws ServletException, IOException {
                  PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
                  writer.println("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>");
               }        
}
```

The following is what i see in **localhost_access_log**:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [21/Jun/2013:13:25:40 -0500] "POST /manager/html/deploy?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=435C56002971030D163AA1C798F91722 HTTP/1.1" 200 14076
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Jun/2013:13:28:50 -0500] "GET /website/home HTTP/1.1" 405 1065
```

**manager_log**:

```
Jun 21, 2013 1:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Jun 21, 2013 1:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Jun 21, 2013 1:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: install: Installing context configuration at 'C:\Users\Priyankar\workspace\website\website.xml'
Jun 21, 2013 1:25:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

The rest appear to be normal to me unless you wanted to have a look at any specific log file.

**error message:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class website.web.TestServlet

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class website.web.TestServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class website.web.TestServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: website.web.TestServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

Here's the screen shot of the project tree from the package explorer:

[image]

Comment: Post the part you're making this GET request from.

Comment: I think I'd expect to see the writer being closed ....

Comment: localhost:8080/website/home

Comment: @DaveHowes Tried doing that now. Did not work either.

Comment: Do you see anything interesting in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Edited the question. Added the log files.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong. Can you undeploy, restart, change your servlet name, update web.xml and deploy again. This would basically force a re-compile. If this doesn't work please post a snap shot of your eclipse project structure especially under WEB-INF/classes/..

Comment: Tried doing that but get an error message which i have added to my edit. Copy pasting a screen shot of my workspace as well.

Comment: It would not let me post an image since i need to have 10 reputation points for that. Wish there was some other way.

Comment: Check that you have a TestServlet.class file at `{WORKSPACE}\website\web\WEB-INF\classes\website\web` in Explorer. If not, do a `Project > Clean` from Eclipse.

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your screenshot is for a Java class called `website.web.TestServlet` but your `web.xml` and code posted say `website.web.HomeServlet`.

Comment: Hi i had changed the name to TestServlet in the web.xml file but forgot to edit it here. Now edited the xml file as well to reflect the change.

Answer (score 2):

The class name you gave is TestServlet and your web.xml is HomeServlet. So when you hit the URL it cannot find anything that is called HomeServlet.

Slightly off topic but relevant: You would have caught this during deploying itself if you had the

```
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
```

tag.

That basically loads the Servlet during deploy and if it didn't find any it will throw up. If you don't give that tag, the server loads whenever it feels like.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out now.

Comment: Had edited the actual xml file and it said TestServlet not HomeServlet when i deployed the web app. Its just that forgot to edit it out here. Sorry.